# How to send emails from my Gmail account through another mail service?

Tags: email, gmail, smtp

I want to send an email from my Gmail under another mail address.
(In this case, I want to use the mail service that I have at www.123-reg.co.uk)

Here what I've tried so far:
I clicked "**Add another email address**" at "**Send mail as:**" in the settings menu, and used [this guide](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/123-Mail/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-client-with-123-mail-5098/) (from step 8):

When I've tried to use TLS with port 587 I receive this error message:
`Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.`

`Server returned an error: "Unspecified Error (SENT_EHLO): Unable to send AUTH command over non ssl connection, code: 0"`

And when I used SSL with port 465 I receive this error message:
`Authentication failed. Please check your username/password and less secure apps access for xyz@gmail.com.`

`Server returned an error: "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o49sm108726oto.46 - gsmtp , code: 535"`

I know that my Username and Password of 123-reg are the correct ones (because otherwise I wouldn't be able to enter the site), and the SMTP is *smtp.123-reg.co.uk*

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to enabled "less secure" app access to your account.

First, go to your [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/). On the left navigation panel, click Security.   Near the bottom of the page, in the Less secure app access panel, click on "Turn on access (not recommended)":
[image]

This will bring you to a new screen with a control to click on to enable this access:
[image]

Comment: What you're talking about?
There is nothing like "Less secure app access panel" in there: https://imgur.com/k15Y7M4

Comment: @HashiramaSenju Hmm that's odd,  maybe it's locale specific or something.  I have added screen shots.

Comment: "Less secure app access panel" setting is not available for accounts with 2-Step Verification enabled. Such accounts require an application-specific password for less secure apps access.  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en-GB