# Gmail 'send mail as' setup always fails using an alias from a "separate" Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, smtp, alias

I have a Google **Workspace** account with a single email address: `admin@domain.com`.  I enabled POP access in the **Workspace** account, and also configured an **"alternate email"** (alias): `alternate@domain.com`.

I also have a **personal** (free) Gmail account: `personal@gmail.com`

In the **personal** account, I successfully set up both **"Send mail as"** and **"Check mail from other accounts"** for the **Workspace** account `admin@domain.com`.  This all works well.

However, I cannot figure out how to **"send mail as"** my **Workspace**  alias `alternate@domain.com` from my `personal@gmail.com` account.  When I try to set it up I always get this error: *"Authentication failed. Please check your username/password"* I am using the `app password` as required.

Other Questions that are not Duplicates:

- [Gmail "send mail as" not working. No error messages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95251/gmail-send-mail-as-not-working-no-error-messages)
  User can't "send mail as' via their University server.  Mistakenly thought they were sending using Google servers.  Unrelated.
- [How to send emails from my Gmail account through another mail service?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114494/how-to-send-emails-from-my-gmail-account-through-another-mail-service)
  User can't send mail via 3rd party ([www.123-reg.co.uk](http://www.123-reg.co.uk)) servers.  Not sure the problem.  Single answer was off-base talking about  "less secure" app access.
- [How to send emails from my Gmail account through another mail service?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114494/how-to-send-emails-from-my-gmail-account-through-another-mail-service)
  This is about setting up the regular "send mail as" service using another Gmail address.  Neither the question nor the answers address the situation where the other Gmail address is an alias.  I can already successfully send from my **personal** Gmail address using my **Workspace** address so this information is not useful.
- [How to use Gmail's "Send Mail As" with another Gmail account through SMTP without "On Behalf Of"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/how-to-use-gmails-send-mail-as-with-another-gmail-account-through-smtp-withou)
  When using "send mail as" second Gmail account from first Gmail account, OP's sent messages showed "on behalf of" the first Gmail account to recipients. Not usefull as I can already successfully send from my **personal** Gmail address using my **Workspace** address without showing "on behalf of".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Regardless of whether using a Google Account's primary email address for a "Send As" alias, or an email alias of that account, you must always use the account's username to authenticate via SMTP, and the account's username follows the account's primary email address.

---

## Overview

The instructions that follow are to configure one Gmail account (**"AccountToConfigure"**) to "Send mail as" a Gmail address associated with a separate Google account (**"OtherAccount"**) that you control.

The wrinkle, in this case, is that the messages are being sent on behalf of one of  **OtherAccount**'s email aliases, **`john.doe@wkspc.com`**, rather than its primary email address.

Regardless of this distinction, the setup is almost identical but this distinction often trips users up because they don't specify the correct `username`, and the nuance of the use case is often overlooked by helpers when those same users seek support.

---

## Background Info for OtherAccount

```
Primary Email: john.doe@workspace.com
Username:      john.doe@workspace.com  // is the primary email
Password:      Password1!
Email Aliases: j.doe@workspace.com
               john.d@workspace.com
               john.doe@wkspc.com     // alias used in this example
```

---

## Instructions

Steps to send mail as **`john.doe@wkspc.com`**, an email alias of **OtherAccount**.

1. Get an app password for **OtherAccount**
2. Configure "Send mail as" for **AccountToConfigure**

### Step 1: Get an app password

This step is common regardless of whether you want to "Send mail as" **OtherAccount**'s primary address, or one of its aliases.

You can skip this step if you already have an app password, however, for security reasons, I suggest creating a separate app password each time you need one using an informative label.  This will allow you to remove old ones that may no longer be needed without the risk of impacting multiple places where they may be reused.

**Step 1** is done in  **OtherAccount**. If you are not already logged in to **OtherAccount**, ensure you are logged out of **all** other accounts and authenticate with **OtherAccount**'s credentials when prompted by Google.

1. Navigate to Google's App Passwords page: [myaccount.google.com/apppasswords](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)
   [image]
   Alternatively, while logged in to your [Google Account](https://accounts.google.com), select **Security**, then **2-Step Verification** (under "How you sign in to Google"), and then **App passwords** (at the bottom of the page).
   <sup><sub>See [Google Help > Sign in with app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)</sub></sup>
2. Specify an informative app name such as: `"send mail as john.doe@wkspc.com"` and then click **<kbd>Create</kbd>**
   <sub>[image]</sub>
3. Copy the generated app password, **`mhaq pdiy mnfc hhnc`** in this example, then click **<kbd>Done</kbd>**
   <sub>[image]</sub>

### Step 2: Configure "Send mail as"

This portion is done while logged in to **AccountToConfigure**.  You can first log in to that account or start logged out of any account and authenticate with **AccountToConfigure** when prompted by Google.

1. Access the Gmail settings  for **"Accounts and import"** at

   - [mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts)
   - alternatively, in Gmail, click **Settings** (top right), then **See all settings**, then (depending what you see), the **Accounts and import** or **Accounts** tab.
     <sub>See also [Google Help: Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370)</sub>

   2. Click **Add another email address** located at the bottom of the "Send mail as" section.
   3. In the "Add another email address you own" dialog click **<kbd>Next step »</kbd>** after specifying the following values:
      [image]

      ```
      Name:          John Doe             // customize as you prefer
      Email address: john.doe@wkspc.com   // alias in "this" case
      Alias:         ☑ Treat as an alias
      ```
   4. In the SMTP server settings, click  **<kbd>Add Account »</kbd>** after specifying the following values:
      <sub>[image]</sub>

      ```
      SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
      Username:    john.doe@workspace.com  // *always* the primary email address
      Password:    mhaqpdiymnfchhnc        // the app password without spaces
      Port:        587
      Connection:  ☑ Secured connection using TLS
      ```

Answer (score 0):

At first time when asked for mail address then put "alternate@domain.com" and second time when again asked for mail address put "admin@domain.com". It worked for me. I used 16 letter App password. Both POP and SMTP disabled so that doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I have figured out to do it (based on the other answer), I can confirm that this answered the question, but it wasn't very clear. Specifically, it wasn't clear what 'at first time when asked for mail address' and 'second time' was referring to. Just wanted to give that feedback! Thanks for the answer.